# Property 'email' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: typescript, next.js, formik

Please I have problem with TS, if I uncomment the line 3 the value of the email will become ''.. How can I remove the TS error **Property 'email' does not exist on type '{}'**?

```
export default function loginValidate(values: any) {
  let errors = {
    // email:'', //handling = Property 'email' does not exist on type '{}'
    // password: '', //handling = Property 'password' does not exist on type '{}'
  };


  if (!values.email) {
    errors.email = 'Email Required';
  } else if (!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(values.email)) {
    errors.email = 'Invalid email address';
  }

  //Validation for password
  if (!values.password) {
    errors.password = 'Password Required';
  } else if (values.password.length < 6 || values.password.length > 30) {
    errors.password = "Must be greater than 6 and less than 30 characters"
  } else if (values.password.includes(" ")) {
    errors.password = "Invalid Password";
  }

  return errors;

}
```

[image]

**Fixed**

let errors = {} to **let errors: any = {}**

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code. Copy and paste the code and wrap it in ``` to format it as code.

Comment: ok please give me a sec

Comment: `let errors = {}` implicitly defines the type as an object with no properties. If you want it to have an optional `email` property then you should *explicitly* define the type.

Comment: Fixed  let errors: = {}  to  let errors: any = {} Thanks @Quentin

Comment: Avoid `any`. It throws away all the benefits of using TypeScript. Give it an explicit type.

Comment: any suggestion i'm new to TS...

Comment: @erwin — https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html